# unexpected token in webpack/lib/Compiler.js apply: util.deprecate((...args) => {

Tags: javascript, webpack, variadic-functions

I'm trying to set up easy node/react project with webpack. I follow this tutorial:
https://spinspire.com/article/creating-expressjs-environment-webpack-react-and-babel-configurations
After configuring webpack when trying to run the server I got an error:

```
/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:96
                apply: util.deprecate((...args) => {
                                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/zaba/code/CurrencyCalc/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zaba/code/CurrencyCalc/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)

npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-37-generic 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" 
npm ERR! node v5.12.0 
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! currencycalc@1.0.0 start: `babel-node buildScripts/server.js` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR!  Failed at the currencycalc@1.0.0 start script 'babel-node buildScripts/server.js'. 
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. 
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the currencycalc package, 
npm ERR! not with npm itself. 
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: 
npm ERR!     babel-node buildScripts/server.js 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: 
npm ERR!   npm bugs currencycalc 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls currencycalc 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/zaba/code/CurrencyCalc/npm-debug.log
```

Is it really problem with webpack or should I look for an error in my code? And if so where? Google is not very useful in that...

Comment: Not sure, but according to [this](http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-arrow-functions), node v5.12.0 doesn't have perfect arrow-function support (even though it does have the spread operator).  Are you able to update to a newer node.js, or to add babel to your project?

Comment: I have babel added. My node version is 5.12.0. I'll try to update that.

Comment: I updated node.js to 8.10.0 version and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: yes, the deconstructing syntax, i.e. `...` is not suported by node 5.12.0 and webpack is run directly by node, not babel.

Comment: @cxw sure, with pleasure! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate the information in case anyone else runs into the same problem, the issue was Node version.  Webpack is run by node, and the node version was 5.12.0 per the error message.  The error line uses [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).†  Per [the compatibility table](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-rest-parameters), node 5.12.0 does not support rest parameters without the `--harmony` flag.  However, updating to a newer node is a better idea than using a flag if you can manage it :) .

† `...` is "rest parameters" when used in an argument list, but ["spread syntax"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in other contexts.